# Sqlite Browser goes non responsive while inserting data into sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing and android application for ELearning purpose.Now in this application I want to store the questions and answers in the sqlite database.My following query works fine when the question/answer is of 1 line only.But application hangs when i try to enter a multiline answer.

Please help me how to resolve it or suggest any other option for doing this.

**QUERY :**

- This works fine :

  INSERT INTO ques_ans VALUES(3,'What are the principle
     concepts of OOPS? ','Object oriented programming organizes a program
     around its data')

**EDIT**

- while querying following data sqlite browser hangs:

  INSERT INTO ques_ans VALUES(3,'what is the java? ','Java is a
     programming language and computing platform first released by Sun
     Microsystems in 1995.There are lots of applications and websites that
     won't work unless you have Java installed, and more are created every
     day. Java is fast, secure, and reliable. From laptops to datacenters,
     game consoles to scientific supercomputers, cell phones to the
     Internet, Java is everywhere. It is the underlying technology that
     powers state-of-the-art programs including utilities, games, and
     business applications.')

While i try to insert the above mentioned multiline data no row is created in my sqlite table

Comment: What are the details of the 3rd column you're inserting? Also I suggest you use the `INSERT INTO table (columns list) VALUES (values list)` syntax to make sure you're inserting the data on the correct column.

Comment: @m0skit0 : thanks for the response the columns of the table are (_ID,Question,Answer)

Comment: I actually meant type...

Comment: ok the type is (int,text,text)

Comment: Can you try and reduce the length of third column data?

Comment: Are there any error messages in logcat?

Comment: see the edit in question we are not adding records using code we are using sqlite browser to add records to table and then we use that table in our application

Comment: @Shruti: After you provided the link, I tried. You're right. It's busted! +1 for the question. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a better way to find a solution. So here goes what I've tried:

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUSL9.jpg)

This isn't really a technical solution, but as I mentioned, I couldn't/didn't really find a better way to address this issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: the image is not visible please add the image

Comment: I could see it. How about now? Are you able to see it now?

Comment: How about now? Ah! This is annoying. SOme idotic bug this turned out to be.

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with SqliteBrowser freezing, so I starting using [TKSqlite](http://reddog.s35.xrea.com/wiki/TkSQLite.html) instead.